# If textarea contains certain string then

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I am creating a contact form for my website, and I am adding a few joke easter eggs which trigger if a user chooses a certain option or in this case happens to type a certain string into the message textarea.
I would like to be able to trigger the action as they type...

I have tried to use indexOf(), but that didn't work or maybe I was using it wrong.

```
$("#id_message").keyup(function(){
    if($('#id_message').val().indexOf('foo') > -1){
        // do something
    }
});
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: did you add jQuery(document).ready wrapper around your code ? https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I tested your code and it works, so there is probably another mistake. Possibly a typo in the id, or setting the event at the wrong time.

Comment: @GolezTrol I could not get my code to work. I understood the theory of what I as trying to do. The slight change that Waqas Ibrahim made below, has solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#id_message").on('keyup', function(){
    if($('#id_message').val().indexOf('foo') > -1){
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: This may be the (or at least *a*) solution, but a bit of context would make the answer much better.

Comment: This solution works! Thank you.  Out of interest, is there a way to disregard case sensitivity?  So that if a user enters "Foo" or "FOO" that the code will still work?

Comment: You can use `$('#id_message').val().toLowerCase()` and compare it with a lower case word.